# How to enable null safety for install geoflutterfire on Dart SDK version 3.0.3?

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I got this error when try to install geoflutterfire by terminal. But my SDK is higher than 2.12.0.

```
ben@MacBook projectva % flutter pub add geoflutterfire
The current Dart SDK version is 3.0.3.

Because geoflutterfire >=3.0.0-nullsafety.1 <3.0.0-nullsafety.3 depends on rxdart ^0.26.0 and geoflutterfire >=3.0.0-nullsafety.3 <3.0.1 depends on cloud_firestore ^2.0.0, geoflutterfire
  >=3.0.0-nullsafety.1 <3.0.1 requires rxdart ^0.26.0 or cloud_firestore ^2.0.0.
And because geoflutterfire <2.2.3 doesn't support null safety, geoflutterfire <2.2.3-∞ or >=3.0.0-nullsafety.1 <3.0.1-∞ requires rxdart ^0.26.0 or cloud_firestore ^2.0.0.
And because geoflutterfire >=2.2.3 <3.0.0-nullsafety.1 depends on cloud_firestore ^3.1.6 and geoflutterfire >=3.0.1 <3.0.2 depends on cloud_firestore ^2.3.0, geoflutterfire <3.0.2 requires
  rxdart ^0.26.0 or cloud_firestore >=2.0.0 <3.0.0 or ^3.1.6.
And because geoflutterfire >=3.0.2 depends on cloud_firestore ^3.1.6 and okleva depends on cloud_firestore ^4.7.0, every version of geoflutterfire requires rxdart ^0.26.0.
So, because okleva depends on both rxdart ^0.27.7 and geoflutterfire any, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.28.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
```

My versions on pubspec.yaml
cloud_firestore: ^4.7.0
rxdart: ^0.27.7

I try search for a solution to change the Dart SDK but i found that In Dart 3, null safety is built in; you cannot turn it off. [(https://dart-ko.dev/resources/dart-3-migration)](https://(https://dart-ko.dev/resources/dart-3-migration))

So can somebody help to solve this. And install geoflutterfire ?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My usual strategy when facing such errors is to:

1. make a backup copy of `pubspec.yaml` and `pubspec.lock` (git commit!)
2. change all version constraints to "any" (or just make them empty)
3. `flutter clean; flutter pub get`

*If* that can solve for some combination of versions, I compare the versions from `flutter pub deps` and see if anything had to go a major version, and if so, review their changelog to see if there's breaking changes.

If that all makes sense, I test the app.  If *that* works, I carefully copy the dependencies from `pubspec.lock` back into `pubspec.yaml`.

I'm sure someone will tell me "oh, that's just flutter pub SomeWeirdCommand to do it all".  Oh well.  This works. :)

Comment: I did that and found this link https://iiro.dev/resolving-dart-package-version-conflicts/ with a solution like your. But now there is a new error. ...Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'.
[  +18 ms] [   +3 ms]     FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate); ...Error: The method 'FallThroughError' isn't defined for the
class 'ActionCodeInfo'.

Comment: for any chance is possible have all firebase packages in pubspec.yaml file for any SDK3 and build the app without throw errors? if there is a way please colud you present the right versions of the firebase packages and SDK?

Comment: You probably have some migrations to do for updates to some of your items.  Firebase in particular went through a couple of breaking changes in the past.

Comment: And what kind of migrations can be
Should I use another SDK? What can you suggest me practically?  I've been looking for solutions everywhere and I can't find. Thanks now. you are a good person

Comment: Solved. thanks again [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76769266/10296934)

Answer (score 0):

For more info about resolving-dart-package-version-conflicts
https://iiro.dev/resolving-dart-package-version-conflicts/

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.